# Is this considered as a copy constructor?

Tags: c++, oop, copy-constructor

I know that a copy constructor is a constructor that makes a new object as a copy of an existing object, but, is every constructor that takes another object as an argument called a copy constructor?

Example: If I have to classes `X` and `Y` is `X(const Y& y)` a copy constructor?

If not is there a name for such constructor?

Comment: what language are you talking about?

Comment: It depends on the language; most languages, if not all, don't actually *require* that you use the object passed as an argument to initialize the new object.

Comment: That's a converting constructor.

Comment: A copy constructor should take a reference to an object of the same type as the argument. The reference can be either const or non-const...

Comment: The copy constructor is supposed to make a copy of itself, that's why it's called that way. If you take another type (class or struct or whatever), then it just a constructor. You can have multiple constructors and you can take multiple types of classes in your constructor. But you can have only one copy constructor. As a matter of fact, even if you don't define it, C++ will create one for you.

Comment: Related note: if you have a constructor that looks like that, it can be used by the compiler to implicitly convert objects of type Y to objects of type X. If this is undesired behavior, it can be removed by putting the keyword 'explicit' before the constructor. Doing so is usually considered 'good form' :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this

```
X(const Y& y);
```

is not a copy constructor. The copy constructor shall define the first parameter having the same type (with/without qualifiers) as the created object

According to the C++ Standard

> 2 A non-template constructor for class X is a copy constructor if its
>   first parameter is of type X&, const X&, volatile X& or const volatile
>   X&, and either there are no other parameters or else all other
>   parameters have default arguments

Constructor

```
X(const Y& y);
```

is a conversion constructor that converts an object of type Y to an object of type X.

Answer (score 5):

No.  A copy constructor is one which takes a single instance of the same class as it a ctor for.  Hence

```
 X(const X& x)
```

is a copy constructor, as would be:

```
 X(const X& x, int z = 0)
```

since it can be called with just the single `x` object.

Constructors which take some other object are often called "converting constructors", but that name is as fixed as "copy constructor".

Answer (score 1):

If `X` and `Y` are different types, then

```
X(const Y& y)
```

would be a *conversion* constructor.

Note that *copy* constructor is considered a special case of *conversion* constructor (for `X==Y`).